# Unable to create a constant value of type 'T'

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a table called **Subjects**,

I have an another Table called **Allocations**, which stores the Allocations of the Subjects

I have a **Datagridview**, which is populated with Subject Allocations from the **Allocations** Table

Now i need to get the **Subjects** that are **not** in the **Datagridview**

To do this

1. I Get All **Subjects** from the **ObjectContext**
2. Now i get all the **Subjects** that are alloted **from** the **Datagridview** (It Returns me an **InMemory** Collection)
3. Now i use the LINQ.EXCEPT method to filter the results, but it is throwing me the Following Exception,

> "Unable To Create Constant Value of Type "ObjectContext.Subjects"  Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

Below is my Code

```
    public static IOrderedQueryable<Subject> GetSubjects()
    {
        return OBJECTCONTEXT.Subjects.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
    }

    private IQueryable<Subject> GetAllocatedSubjectsFromGrid()
    {
          return (from DataGridViewRow setRow in dgv.Rows          
                    where !setRow.IsNewRow
                    select setRow.DataBoundItem).Cast<Allocation>()  //I know the Problem lies somewhere in this Function
                    .Select(alloc =>alloc.Subject).AsQueryable();
    }

    private void RUN()
    {
        IQueryable<Subject> AllSubjects = GetSubjects(); //Gets

        IQueryable<Subject> SubjectsToExclude = GetAllocatedSubjectsFromGrid();

        IQueryable<Subject> ExcludedSubjects = AllSubjects.Except(SubjectsToExclude.AsEnumerable());   
        //Throwing Me "Unable to create a constant value of type 'OBJECTCONTEXT.Subject'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."
    }
```

As a result of googling i found that it happens because LINQ can't compare between InMemory collection(Records from DGV) and Objectcontext(FromDB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little short of time, have not tested it. But I guess you can try to get it all in memory. So instead of using

```
  IQueryable<Subject> AllSubjects = GetSubjects(); //Gets
```

You do

```
List<Subject> AllSubjects = GetSubjects().ToList(); //

List<Subject> SubjectsToExclude = GetAllocatedSubjectsFromGrid().ToList();    

List<Subject> ExcludedSubjects = AllSubjects.Except(SubjectsToExclude);
```

Comment: This works quite well, but there is a potential 'gotcha' that should be noted: that if the different list of <T> are not identical (that is, if one list contains child objects the other doesn't) it won't work. Something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by comparing keys in a `Where` clause rather than using `Except`.

So instead of:

```
var SubjectsToExclude = GetAllocatedSubjectsFromGrid();
var ExcludedSubjects = AllSubjects.Except(SubjectsToExclude.AsEnumerable());
```

Something more like:

```
var subjectsToExcludeKeys =
   GetAllocatedSubjectsFromGrid()
   .Select(subject => subject.ID);

var excludedSubjects =
   AllSubjects
   .Where(subject => !subjectsToExcludeKeys.Contains(subject.ID));
```

(I'm guessing what your entity's key looks like though.)

This allows you to keep everything in Entity Framework, rather than pulling everything into memory.